# Given a function, is it possible to find an orthogonal function?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality

Given a function $f(x)$, I want to find another function such that $<f, g> = 0$, in the space $R([0, pi])$ with the inner product $L^2$. The only way I've been able to do it is by trial and error. That is, I set up an integral an try on function and then evaluate the integral, to see if the result is 0.

But is there really no other, smarter way? I don't want a trivial solution ( $g = 0$).

Comment: Take $g=0$. $\quad$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe that's not very helpful...

Comment: It was a way to ask you to precise the question. Which inner product are you considering ? On which space ? What *exactly* are you looking for ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, right sorry, my bad. I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: Looks pretty much like the XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need that $g$?

Comment: What is $R([0,\pi])$?

Answer (score 2):

If $\int f=0$, then any constant function is solution.

If $\int f \neq 0$, then for every function $h$, a solution is given by $$g(x)=h(x)- \frac{\int fh}{\int f}$$

Comment: Excuse-me, h is any function at all? Could you explain the intuition behind that solution?

Comment: Can you write down the inner product between such a $g$ and your function $f$ ?

Comment: You mean, the integral? integral(f*g) from 0 to pi?

Comment: Yes, this is your inner-product

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it... I chose h(x) to be x and indeed it works. But I still don't get how you arrived at that formula and I badly want to know the logic behind it

Comment: Don't choose a specific $h$, and don't work with your specific $f$. Given any function $f$ such that $\int f \neq 0$ and $h$, write down the inner product between $f$ and the given $g$. Make the calculations in terms of $f$ and $h$, and see why it is always $0$.

Comment: I tried deriving it with integration by parts. It didn't work. Please, please, explain it clearly.

Comment: You have to compute $$\int_0^{\pi} f(x) \left( h(x)- \frac{\int_0^{\pi} f(t)h(t) dt}{\int_0^{\pi} f(t)dt}\right) dx$$ Can't you see how this can be done ? **Hint** Just use the linearity of the integral and nothing else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115442/discussion-between-daniel-oscar-and-thesilverdoe).

Comment: Do you have a source for this insight?

Comment: @JennyReininger Not really, this answer is based on a simple calculation, as explained in the previous comments.